# Q: Why It is necessary to import react to develop a react-native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react native app But I didn't get the reason of importing react with it.

Comment: React-native is based on React. That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

It says in react-native website:
"React Native combines the best parts of native development with React, a best-in-class JavaScript library for building user interfaces."

so React-native uses ReactJS, and you need to import it to use it.

Answer (score 0):

React is the library that builds UI from JSX (Components, props, state, etc) 
React native translates that UI into native